# How can i access a global variable in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to update a label in kivy with a global variable in python. How can I do that

The final result I need is to update the pos of canvas according to the switch interrupt.

#### .Py

```
global x1

def hi():
    print "hi"
    x1 = 20
    print x1
class Mode1(Screen):
    global x1
    x1 = NumericProperty()
    y1 = NumericProperty()
    Buttonstatus = ''
    ButtonPressed=''

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print 'x1'
        global x1
        print x1
        hi()
```

#### .KV

```
canvas.after:
    Color:
        rgb:[1, 0, 0,1]
    Rectangle:
        pos:root.x1,root.y1
        size:20,20
```

Comment: Post a full example demonstrating what you think should work but doesn't, your current example doesn't even include a Label.

Comment: I am trying to update the position of that canvas not to update label hope you can help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the position of the canvas - you mean you want to move the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already declared x1 as a global variable in your class. In your method try printing self.x1."
print self.x1"

Comment: yes that's right but can I do it without self. because I need to replace _def on_touch_move(self, touch):_ with a callback function